# FileNotFoundException when trying to Load Game Data from save file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.io.file

I am unsure why I am getting this error;

FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "........\New Unity Project\Assets\Saves\NewGame"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

[System.Serializable]

public class PlayerStatistics  : MonoBehaviour
{

private string _loadGameName;
//all save variables, only leaving one example
private int _decision1;

    public void ChangeGameLoadName(string LoadGameName)
    {
            _loadGameName = LoadGameName;
            Debug.Log("Load Game Name Received by Player Stats as : " + LoadGameName) ;
    }
    public void PlayerLoadGameData()
    {
            string LoadName = _loadGameName;
            Debug.Log("Attempting to load game with the filename: " + LoadName);
            BinaryFormatter loadGameBF = new BinaryFormatter();
            string ApplicationFolder = Application.dataPath;
            string saveGameDirectory = ApplicationFolder + "/Saves/";
            FileStream loadFile = File.Open(saveGameDirectory + LoadName, FileMode.Open);
            Save load = (Save)loadGameBF.Deserialize(loadFile);
            loadFile.Close();

            _decision1 = load._decision1;
            //other save vars here

            Debug.Log("GameInfoLoaded in player stats");
            TakeLoadGameAndPlay();
    }
}
```

The Debug.Log in ChangeGameLoadName is printing the correct name e.g. Load Game Name Received by Player Stats as : Google.save

The "Attempting to load game with the filename:" prints as NewGame.
For reference, the user presses a button which invokes ChangeGameLoadName(), then another button which invokes PlayerLoadGameData().
I don't know where it is getting this "NewGame" from at all. Any help would be very appreciated.

EDIT:

ChangeGameLoadName() is called from my GameManager script through this function:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Script References
    GameView GameViewScript;
    PlayerStatistics PlayerStatisticsScript;
    GameObject GlobalObject;
    PlayerOptions PlayerOptionsScript;
    PlayerInput PlayerInputScript;
    StoryHandler StoryHandlerScript;
    GameHUD GameHUDScript;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _storyScripts;

    private float _shortFadeSpeed = 0.75f;
    private float _longFadeSpeed = 1.5f;
    private float _longLongFadeSpeed = 3f;

    private void Start()
    {
        GameViewScript = GetComponent<GameView>();
        PlayerInputScript = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        StoryHandlerScript = _storyScripts.GetComponent<StoryHandler>();
        GlobalObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GlobalScripts");
        PlayerStatisticsScript = GlobalObject.GetComponent<PlayerStatistics>();
        PlayerOptionsScript = GlobalObject.GetComponent<PlayerOptions>();
        GameHUDScript = GetComponent<GameHUD>();

    }

    public void LoadGameNameHUDtoPlayerStatistics(string LoadGameName)
    {
        PlayerStatisticsScript.ChangeGameLoadName(LoadGameName);
        Debug.Log("Game Manager Received Name and Sent it to Player Stats. Name = "+ LoadGameName);
    }

}
```

The above debug log prints correctly. (as google.save if my savefilename was google.save)

Which in turn was called from:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpecialPrefabLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameManager GameManagerScript;

    public void GetLoadGameNameAndFeedToLoad()
    {
        GameObject Canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        GameManagerScript = Canvas.GetComponent<GameManager>();

        string LoadGameName = this.gameObject.name;
        GameManagerScript.LoadGameNameHUDtoPlayerStatistics(LoadGameName);
        Debug.Log("Found Save Game and Sent Info to Game Manager");
    }
}
```

This was a special script because its attached to a prefab button which instantiates the load game buttons. I couldn't find an alternate way to do this.
This was called by the OnClick() Unity Function.

The gameObject.name was set here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System.IO;

public class GameHUD : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioMixer _globalAudio;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _faderBackgroundObject;
    [SerializeField]
    private Image _faderBackground;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _menuMainGame;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _menuButtons;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _saveGameMenu;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _loadGameMenu;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _optionsMenu;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _audioOptions;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _gameplayOptions;

    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _globalVolumeSlider;
    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _bgmVolumeSlider;
    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _fxVolumeSlider;

    private float _longFadeSpeed = 1.5f;
    private float _shortFadeSpeed = 0.5f;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _canvas;
    private GameManager GameManagerScript;

    public Text inputText;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _gameSavedNotification;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _loadGameScroller;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _prefabLoadGameButton;

    private void Start()
    {
        GameManagerScript = _canvas.GetComponent<GameManager>();
        SetGameSettingsFromPlayerPrefs();
    }

    private void GetPlayerLoadGameList()
    {
        string ApplicationFolder = Application.dataPath;
        string[] saveFolder = Directory.GetFiles(@ApplicationFolder + "/Saves/", "*.save");
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string saveGameFile in saveFolder)
        {
            i = i + 1;

            GameObject myNewObj = Instantiate(_prefabLoadGameButton, _loadGameScroller.transform);
            myNewObj.transform.position = new Vector3(_loadGameScroller.transform.position.x + 250, _loadGameScroller.transform.position.y - (i * 20), 0);
            myNewObj.name = saveGameFile;
            Text saveGameName = myNewObj.GetComponent<Text>();
            saveGameName.text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(saveGameFile);
            myNewObj.name = saveGameName.text + ".save";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you probably want to use `Application.PersistentDataPath`

Comment: I'm going to change that later anyway to save to docs and settings so its fine for now, I think.

Comment: In general use `Path.Combine` for system paths! Directly concatenating strings using `+ "/"` might fail depending on the target platform. I would add some `Debug.Log` for seeing which paths is being tried to read from ... if there is no such file then .. well it doesn't exist ... ;)

Comment: `LoadGameName` comes in as a parameter .. of you don't know where it comes from then who should?

Comment: @ derHugo No, I do know where it comes from, and if its making it to the debug log correctly then it's making it that far. Which should? mean that _loadGameName should be the same as the name that prints in the debug log. Or am I wrong?

I'll change that to Path.Combine though, thank you. Didn't know that was an option as all the examples I learned from just used it this way.

Comment: so like so?
```
string saveGameDirectory = Path.Combine(ApplicationFolder, "Saves");
```

Comment: wild guess here but...you probably have a "new game" button, right? Maybe the string gets overwriten everytime?
Please provide more code, example, where ChangeGameLoadName gets called, etc

Comment: Sorry, I pasted all the code I think is attached to this function. I've probably done it stupidly, sorry. But here it all is. I put it in as an edit to the main question because comments have no code blocks

Comment: urgh, sorry, I forgot to add where my script variables are being declared, Ill edit again

Comment: Yo. You might want to consider posting all of your source code somewhere new, and then removing as many bits as you can to try and narrow down the problem. This process in and of itself might solve the problem, and will also help to have the problem much more clearly defined.

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try, thanks. I was hoping it was something small I'd missed because I haven't been developing for very long, but it's about time I learned to do some bug fixing.

Comment: Ok, so I took everything related to my save and load game system, and replicated it up into a fresh project in unity, and it all works. So I guess something else is interfering somewhere, and I'm just going to have to look for it. Thank you for the help though everyone.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why this works? I decided to completely bypass setting the _loadGameName because I was sure that the string was getting to the ChangeGameLoadName() function. So it now looks like this:
`
        public void ChangeGameLoadName(string LoadGameName)
    {
        PlayerLoadGameData(LoadGameName);
    }
`
... And this works perfectly, other than I need the break between selecting a load game, and confirming the load (For UX purposes).
But I don't understand why what I was doing before didn't work. No other functions act on the _loadGameName variable.

Comment: Is there some chance that it was set as readonly somehow? I thought you had to define it as read only for it to be read only, but maybe someone more knowledgeable might be able to point me in the right direction? I'm going to look into how system.serializable might have affected my variables but I don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

Bit old, but I thought I'd say. It was an instance issue.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)